# Can I upgrade SQL Server express to Standard version on different machine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

If I have a new install of SQL Server Standard on one machine, can I easily import my database from SQL Server Express on another machine?  I was planning to detach the db transfer the file and attach on new machine. Is this the easiest way? What about permissions? Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that approach will work. For more information on the security ramifications, please see the MSDN article "[Securing Data and Log Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189128.aspx)". There's also a good knowledgebase article on [How to move SQL Server databases to a new location by using Detach and Attach functions in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224071) (see the section on "Moving user databases").